# What is the point of staying alive if everyone dies eventually?

Tags: life

## We all will die one day.

We all know the life is difficult. We may live long lives, but death will come sooner or later for everyone. It is inevitable. Why should we bother living at all, facing the difficulties that it offers, if it is simply going to end one day.

## What's the point?

Comment: Indeed, if life is hard, would it be any better to live if we were never to die?

Comment: Ummm....because the alternative is death. We are nothing if not replicating machines driven by the desire to propagate and live.

Comment: @johnathan I think his point is that such knowledge doesn't make it any more meaningful to live (if anything, it makes it seem like even more of a waste if you believe that "we are nothing").

Comment: While I'm glad to see you've found an answer you like, questions like this aren't constructive because they are too broad in scope. "What is the meaning/purpose of life" is not reasonably answered, esp. without specific references or citations. See [this](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2033/the-meaning-of-life) and [this](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2899/life-is-illogical) for similar attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why we should ? There is no reason actually. Out of millions of your father's sperms only one survived to become you, all others are where they statistically supposed to be - dead, dissolved, recycled, dissipated. Any life is a direct violation of natural state of the world, which is chaos. Intelligent life and intelligent civilization is in fact horrible, scary anomaly.

Yet, we are the survivors. We are the anomaly. We defy statistics by our own existence. Our life was not deserved or earned by us in any way. We, living humans, have just been extremely lucky. And so - even if we are about to live just a few decades, why not use this life for something fun ?

Comment: I tell u something, This comment brought a change in my thoughts. Thamks, I felt to be lucky now :)

Answer (score 1):

The reasons for people to live are different. First of all you could divide the group into those believing in an afterlife and those who dont.
Afterlife-People maybe want to live not to ruin their afterlife, because e.g. suicide could get you into hell.
For those who don´t believe in an afterlife, they have something to do here, as you pointed out that may be love, relationships, responsibilities etc. Also, it maybe just the fun of living, the emotions, maybe fear of death is something that keeps you going, too.
To sum it up, there are as much answers to your question as there are humans living on this planet, because everyone living has a reason to do it, those who don´t have a reason would end their lifes, since if they fear death, that again is a reason to live.

There is also a thread about suicide here: [Rationality of Suicide?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2879/rationality-of-suicide)